# Cannot change the frame properties of a UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, frame, nskeyedarchiver

I have a UIView

```
@IBOutlet weak var myView: UIView!
```

I copy it using NSArchiver

```
var topview = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(self.myView));
```

I attempt to alter it using CGRectMake

```
topview?.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height * 1.5)
```

In response to the line above's '=' I receive the error

```
Cannot assign to result of this expression
```

I have attempted a variety of ways to alter topview's frame properties though each try is eventually met with this error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`unarchiveObjectWithData` returns an optional AnyObject and AnyObject itself does not have frame property. So you need to cast topView to UIView

```
var topview = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(self.myView)) as? UIView
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I am new to Swift and in my early years of programming so I miss stuff that may be obvious to others. With time I'll get it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding:

Because `topview` is an optional, frame is also optional. That means that there's a chance that frame is nil. So then you'd be assigning a `CGRect` to `nil`. Which is not possible.

This should work:

```
if let view = topview as? UIView {
    view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height * 1.5)
}
```